# Eclipse with float values display in watch window

Tags: c++, eclipse

I want to see the float type of data type with its value in watch window of eclipse.
                                                                                     But I am not able to find the option for float variable in watch window .
Can anybody tell me How i can see this variable in watch window .
I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) goto `Window->show View->Memory` .
2) Then click on `+` symbol.
3) Add the name of your variable .
4) Click on `Floating Point` option .

This way you can see the floating point variable in memory .You can view the variable in 32 bit and 64 bit FP format .

Comment: Thanks user3476225 for your answer .